# Text overflowing out of textbox margins

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am using Powerpoint 2016 to create an academic poster. I defined rounded-rectangle textboxes to hold the contents of each of the different sections (Introduction, Methods, etc), and have divided each textbox into 2 or 3 columns for optimal text layout.

Normally, when text that I type reaches the bottom part of the textbox, it is pushed forward to the start of the next column, but sometimes (randomly, seems to me!) text is intead pushed down beyond the lower margin of the textbox, as you can see here:

[image]

The settings of the textbox are as follows:

[image]

I've fiddled with these and other settings, but I could not change this behavior. Resizing the textbox doesn't help, nor does changing the autofit/shrink/wrap options under ShapeOptions|Size&Properties. Any idea how I can prevent text from overspilling out of the borders of the textbox?

Comment: Using the same settings as you've shown here (thanks for including the screenshot), I can't get this to reproduce, either in a rounded rectangle or in a plain text box. Have you found a way of provoking the problem that works consistently?

Comment: I haven't unfortunately, no, this is why I say the problem seems to occur randomly to me :( I realise this means it will be hard/impossible to solve. What I can do, if you would like, is send you the pptx file...

Comment: I'll pass for now, but if you can work out how to provoke the problem, then definitely put the file on dropbox/onedrive/the like and post a link here.

Comment: Alright, will do

Comment: I really see no way to reproduce this, so anyone who wishes to have a try at diagnosing this can find minimal working example [here](https://we.tl/t-pUvcCQdMJH)

Comment: Have you tried activating the "Resize Shape to fit text" option?

Comment: That option would actually not work for me, as I need the textboxes to be of a fixed size. I would just need the text (at a fontsize that I selected so that all text fits neatly inside the textbox) to not overflow.